# Firebase UI signInSuccessWithAuthResult asynchronous

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I tried to use asynchronous code in the `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` of the Firebase UI in order to perform a conditional redirect but it always fails respectively my asynchronous code is not run and my redirect is ignored.

Are you able to use asynchronous code in `signInSuccessWithAuthResult`?
Or do I do something wrong?

```
const uiConfig = {
            signInFlow: 'redirect',
            signInSuccessUrl: appUrl,
            signInOptions: signInOptions,
            tosUrl: appUrl + '/terms',
            privacyPolicyUrl: appUrl + '/privacy',
            credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.GOOGLE_YOLO,
            autoUpgradeAnonymousUsers: true,
            callbacks: {
                signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async (_authResult, _redirectUrl) => {
                    await this.navigateRedirect();

                    return false;
                },
                signInFailure: this.onSignInFailure
            }
        };

private async navigateRedirect() {
     const redirectUrl: string = await get<string>('deckdeckgo_redirect');

    window.location.assign(redirectUrl);
}
```

I use firebaseui v4.0.0. and the above `get` used `idb-keyval`.

Answer (score 2):

The `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback expects a synchronous function. Change to the following:

```
callbacks: {
  signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (_authResult, _redirectUrl) => {
    // This will run asynchronously. When it resolves, it will complete the
    // redirect.
    this.navigateRedirect();
    // In the meantime, disable FirebaseUI redirect.
    return false;
  },
},
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. So you confirm that it needs a synchronous function? Do you know why?